# Kafka helm chart: java.io.IOException: Failed to create data directory /opt/kafka/data/logs

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, amazon-eks

I know this question is already exists but it is something related to Kubernetes or container.

**Chart repository**: `https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/kafka`

```
helm install kafka-test incubator/kafka
```

I am facing the below exception while installing Kafka using helm charts.

```
[2020-06-24 01:54:05,234] INFO Log directory /opt/kafka/data/logs not found, creating it. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2020-06-24 01:54:05,235] ERROR Failed to create or validate data directory /opt/kafka/data/logs (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.io.IOException: Failed to create data directory /opt/kafka/data/logs
    at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$createAndValidateLogDirs$1.apply(LogManager.scala:158)
    at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$createAndValidateLogDirs$1.apply(LogManager.scala:149)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.createAndValidateLogDirs(LogManager.scala:149)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.<init>(LogManager.scala:80)
    at kafka.log.LogManager$.apply(LogManager.scala:953)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:237)
    at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable.startup(SupportedServerStartable.java:114)
    at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka.main(SupportedKafka.java:66)
[2020-06-24 01:54:05,239] ERROR Shutdown broker because none of the specified log dirs from /opt/kafka/data/logs can be created or validated (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

Comment: That chart is deprecated. You might want to look at using Strimzi instead, which offers Kafka related CRDs rather than just a cluster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something related to permission.
I have checked `values.yaml` file.

There is one property

```
## Optional Container Security context
securityContext: {}
```

I have changed that value to like below as a root user

```
## Optional Container Security context
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 0
```

Comment: Is this an answer? Did it solve your problem?

Comment: I can not accept the answer. it shows me after 2 days

Answer (score -1):

Run it as a privileged container.

```
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 0
  privileged: true
```

[Reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/)